# Two loops on different pages do the same thing, but only one page works

Tags: loop

I want to verify a code sent in an email. I do it once to verify your email when you signup and again if youre the winner of the contest. Since its basically the same thing, I reused the same code (just changed the vars names). But it doesnt work. Its always the "Error" message result of the loop thats displayed. Why?

Loop that works perfectly every time:

```
// GET ID FROM EMAIL URL
$verifyEmailCode = $_GET['entry'];


// LOOP THROUGH POST 
$args = array (
    'post_type'             => array( 'custom_type_entries' ),
    'author'                => '1',
    'posts_per_page'        => '-1',
    'meta_query'            => array(
        array(
            'key'           => 'entryCode',
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();

        $postID             = $post->ID;
        $entryCode          = get_post_meta($postID, 'entryCode', true);

        // CONFIRM EMAIL BY CHECKING ENTRY CODES--
        if ($verifyEmailCode == $entryCode) {

                $entryEmail = get_post_meta($postID, 'entryEmail', true);

                // UPDATE ENTRY TO CONFIRM EMAIL ADDRESS IS VALID--
                update_post_meta($postID, 'entryConfirm', '1');

                // UPDATE EMAIL SUBSCRIPTION PREFRENCES--
                update_post_meta($postID, 'entryEmailSubscribe', '1');
                get_footer();
                exit;

        }
        else {

                get_template_part( 'parts/entry', 'codeError' );
                get_footer();
                exit;
        }


    }

} 



// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

The second loop page (to verify the winner) which doesnt work and always returns with the error part of the loop:

```
// GET ID FROM EMAIL URL
$winverifyEmailCode = $_GET['winner'];


// LOOP THROUGH POST 
$winargs = array (
    'post_type'             => array( 'custom_type_entries' ),
    'author'                => '1',
    'posts_per_page'        => '-1',
    'meta_query'            => array(
        array(
            'key'           => 'entryCode',
        ),
    ),
);

$winquery = new WP_Query( $winargs );

if ( $winquery->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $winquery->have_posts() ) {
        $winquery->the_post();

        $winpostID          = $post->ID;
        $winentryCode       = get_post_meta($winpostID, 'entryCode', true);

        // CONFIRM EMAIL BY CHECKING ENTRY CODES--
        if ($winverifyEmailCode == $winentryCode) {

                get_template_part( 'parts/entry', 'winnerWinner' );
                get_footer();
                exit;

        }
        else {

                get_template_part( 'parts/entry', 'winnerError' );
                get_footer();
                exit;
        }


    }

} 



// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: You have a `$_GET` variable that needs to exist e.g. `example.com?winner=12345`; what is the value of `$winverifyEmailCode` and `$winentryCode` respectively during the loop? If the comparison fails; you will end up in the error (`else`) condition.

Comment: I have the _GET for the winner?=12345.

Comment: what is the value of `$winverifyEmailCode` and `$winentryCode` respectively during the loop?